# Problem: Visual Studio Code has 2 Terminals and is defaulting to one of them which is not desired

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am facing a problem on my mac using Visual Studio Code. When I am trying to debug a python code, it is showing two python terminals.

It is getting default to the one which I do not desire, because the code in that does not run. See screenshots:
[image: This works Fine but is not default]

[image: This one is not working at all]